Apply Crank-Nicolson method to wave equation with np.linalg.solve
I want to solve a system of equations, where x,y are the vectors which I want the solutions. And c,d are the solutions. A,B are matrix
x-y=c+d
y-Ax=Bd+c
The full problem which I tried to summarize above is the following one:

The problem is that I know how to apply this method to solve time dependent Schrodinger equation in which partial derivative of time is of order 1 but not to this one. Some solutions?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you know x, y, c, d, A or B, or are these unknowns?

I add a photo of the equations, and the initial conditions are fi=0, phi(0)=sin x
